# How to Use Yield With Pipes / Multiple Processes Python

Tags: python, pipe, yield

I am looking for some guidance regarding a small Python craigslist scanner. Because there are so many craigslist web sites, and I need to run them one by one, I split the scanning into multiple processes using Pipe() (Pipe because supported by AWS Lambda). The application can take between 2 and 8 minutes to run when searching for things in all of US and Canada. Rather than waiting for the lump sum of all results to come back. I would like to return the results of each process when it is done running so I can continually update the client side with the new results.

```
    for i in range(len(site_list)):
        site_counter = site_counter + len(site_list[i])
        processes.append(Process(target=f, args=(site_list[i], event['category'], event['search_query'], child_conn,)))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        yield parent_conn.recv() # My attempt to return the result of each process

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

When I include the yield inside of the function it runs but immediately prints the exit code 0.

What I think the problem is:
I have been reading about yield and generators. I feel as if the process is not done doing its work before the yield runs.
I also am thinking because the process is on another thread before the .Join(), you cannot yield for a function from a different thread.

Comment: `recv` is a blocking function though. Meaning that it will wait until a value is returned or if the Pipe is closed. Does this function run successfully without the yield keyword?

Comment: Yes, if I print the result of the `parent_conn.recv()` I can see the results of the processes print as they finish.

Comment: Could you post how you are using this generator function?